# When are fractions of factorials equal to whole factorials?

Tags: factorial, fractions, pattern-recognition

10!/7!=6!. 6!/3!=5!. Is there something interesting happening in these examples, or are they just coincidence? Is there a way of finding other examples like these?

Comment: I think this has been already asked and I also think that those are coincidences. Of course there are trivial solution as $$\frac{24!}{23!}=4!$$ but I think you do not want to consider them.

Comment: By the way, the second equation actually is such a "trivial" solution , just rearranged.

Comment: @lulu Is $(6,7,10)$ the only "nontrivial" solution with three numbers ?

Comment: @Peter It was, as of a few years ago anyway.  The links attached to the duplicate should have reasonably current information.  Anyway, I believe it's the only example.